# Watertank waves

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator

Say we have a rectangular tank of water and we push it lengthwise. Suppose the surface stays planar. What would be the trajectory of the centre of mass?

Comment: If you start from rest and push on the tank, the surface would not stay planar. The back of the tank would forward on the water, and the water would slosh. The surface would stay planar if the water was frozen.

Comment: "The surface stays planar" - do you mean "the wave length can be assumed to be much greater than the dimensions of the tank"? So that we have a tilting "flat" surface?

Comment: How can the water stay "planar"? For all practical purposes in this problem water is incompressible.

Comment: @mmesser314 I meant a single push.

Comment: Also - when you say "we push it lengthwise" do you mean you impart constant motion, constant force, ...? The question is poorly worded. It's open to lots of different interpretations. And - should this be labeled "homework"?

Comment: @CuriousOne Planar in the sense that it would tilt periodically

Comment: @Floris I am sorry, I didn't even realize the statement was so ambiguous. Also, this is not a homework.

Comment: OK... but that's really not how water moves...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the water surface remains "essentially planar" it has to tilt. In that case the angle of the tilt will have a sinusoidal variation with time, and the center of mass calculation follows from drawing a diagram that shows the two triangles (one above, one below the mean surface) and calculates how much material is in each as a function of time. If the entire tank has linear motion after the push, you obviously would have to add that to the harmonic motion of the center of mass...

[image]

The mass (for width $w$ of the tank) in one "triangle" is $\frac12 \rho L h w$, and its barycenter is at $\frac23 L$ from the center (to the left) of the tank. The height of the barycenter is $\frac13 h$ above the water level.

We can then write the energy as a function of $h$ and tank width $w$:

$$E = m g h \\
= \rho L h/2 g h/3 w\\
= \frac16 \rho L g h^2 w$$

Which is a parabolic energy well - a good first step for simple harmonic motion.

The mass $M=2Ldw\rho$ of the liquid in the tank moves a distance $x$ when the liquid tilts to height $h$:

$$M x = 2\left(\frac12 \rho L h w\right) \left(\frac23 L\right)$$
so
$$x = \frac{\frac23 \rho L^2 h w}{2 \rho L d w}\\
= \frac{Lh}{3d}\\
h = \frac{3dx}{L}$$

The force can be obtained by differentiating the energy:

$$F = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac16 L g \left(\frac{3dx}{L}\right)^2 w\right)\\
=\frac{3 g d^2 x w}{L}$$

In general, when you have

$$M \ddot x = -\alpha x$$

The solution is a simple harmonic motion with

$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{M}}$$

It would be tempting to say that we can therefore solve the equation of motion by stating

$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{3 g d^2 w}{L (2Ldw\rho)}}\\
= \sqrt{\frac{3 g d}{2 L^2 \rho}}$$

BUT: the above makes a giant approximation by going from "the center of mass moves by x" to "I calculate the frequency from this motion". Proving that that is valid would need some careful thought - in particular in relation to the depth, and the fact that the motion of the water is not what we think it is (when some bits of water move faster than others, you can't simply brute-force the equality like I did above: the kinetic energy of the water is not equal to $\frac12 M \dot x^2$).

It would be interesting to think about this problem as two waves traveling in opposite directions (with what wavelength and what speed?) and seeing how that equation corresponds to this one.

Comment: Thank you, but can you please give a hint on how to find how the coordinates of the CM change with relation to each other? I don't see it from the geometry of the problem. Maybe some energy considerations?

Comment: Calculate the energy stored in the tilted water. The mass that "moved" is the triangle of water. Now you have a potential well and a mass - from which you compute the frequency. You will find that the frequency is a function of depth (deeper water - more of the water does not move; so motion of center of mass is less). This is all a bit artificial though.

Comment: There was a typo in my original expression - I fixed it and added parentheses which should make it clear how I obtain the expression $Mx = ...$. See if it makes more sense now - the mass that moves (the first bracketed item) does indeed depend on $h$.